# Zepplin BigQuery connectivity on Dataproc Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, hadoop2, apache-zeppelin

I have setup the one node Dataproc GCP cluster and used the initialization action to install [Zeppelin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/zeppelin) on it.

When I tried to access the sample BigQuery table using simple `select sql` query, it's throwing an error from Zeppelin UI:

```
%bigquery.sql
SELECT * FROM `GCPPJ-238506.ML_DATASET.test`
```

> error details:SQL Execution returned an error!

Please note, I have already setup the credential access for service account as well as below values for settings in BigQuery Interpreter on Zeppelin :

```
zeppelin.bigquery.max_no_of_rows    1000000
zeppelin.bigquery.project_id    GCPPJ-238506
zeppelin.bigquery.sql_dialect   standardSQL
zeppelin.bigquery.wait_time 5000000
```

Comment: Please share your code and more details which can help troubleshoot this

Comment: Check your SQL query, There might be something wrong in the SQL

Comment: @bigbounty  I have updated the question for more details, pls let me know if any details are missed

Answer (score 1):

I followed steps in the provided [Zeppeline](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/zeppelin) link and it worked:

1. Create the cluster with Zeppeline:
   gcloud dataproc clusters create zeppeline \
   --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/zeppelin/zeppelin.sh
2. Create a tunnel:
   gcloud compute ssh zeppeline-m \
   --project=dataproc-training-epam --zone=us-east1-b  -- \
   -4 -N -L 8080:zeppeline-m:8080

   Be sure that you enabled the ingress traffic to port 22 in your master node.
3. Opened the Notebook from the Cloud Shell using the port 8080 and (in the Web Preview).
4. I changed the SQL dialect by setting the property zeppelin.bigquery.sql_dialect=standardSQL. I executed the query and it worked.

Thus, I would recommend:

- Confirm that you can query other datasets and tables to verify that your installation is correct.
- Verify that your dataset and table are accessible, for example, executing the same query from the Bigquery UI.

On the other hand, you can connect Dataproc to Zeppelin through the [Zeppeline Component](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/zeppelin). The web interface is accessed through the Component Gateway which is still in Alpha but you may want to try it.